# How to find Equivalent Resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image: Electric Circuit Diagram]

I am not able to figure out the combination between the two 12ohm resistors. And how will the simplified diagram look like after we figure out the combination between 12ohm resistors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redraw the circuit to make it more understandable:

[image]

As long as all resistor terminals still connect to the same nodes they did before, there's no change to the circuit's behavior.

Comment: I've removed a couple of complete answers to this homework-like question, because Physics.SE isn't a homework-help site. However I think this one is more like guidance, so I'm okay if it remains. Welcome, Jeff.